# Implement page curl when view contents are updated

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a set of worksheets that serially display i.e. as user completes one, the next one appears. In the code, the next worksheet is dynamically generating `UIButtons`/`UILabels` (and other subviews) to render it. I want to display this new worksheet with a page curl animation. Note that the view controller and the top level view remain the same, it's only the sub-views that are being re-created.

Can I use the `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` option to do this with my current approach? It seems like that is only to be used when one view is replaced with another.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. hope this will help u.

[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations: ^ {
        [self.view addSubview:blurView];
    } completion:nil];

here blurView will be your view.